# help understanding exponent simplications

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I'm working my way through a probability textbook and I'm not able to follow the algebra in a section discussing Gambler's Ruin.  The idea is to find solutions for the following equation:

[image]

Where `q` is defined as `1 - p`

[image]

A possible solution is given when `P(a)` is set to `(q/p)^a`, and the reader is meant to verify that this is equal to `P(a)`:

I understand how the following is derived:

[image]

But not this:

[image]

Can someone walk me through the steps of how this part of that derivation works?  It seems to me the final exponent on the right should be `a - 1`.

[image]

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Comment: hmm I have a feeling that there's a mistake in the evaluation of $q\cdot P(a-1)$. In my mind
$$
q P(a-1) = q \left( \frac{q}{p} \right)^{a-1}
= q \left( \frac{q}{p} \right)^{-1}  \left( \frac{q}{p} \right)^{a}
= q \cdot \frac{p}{q} \left( \frac{q}{p} \right)^{a}
= p \left( \frac{q}{p} \right)^{a}
$$
However, in the continuation, the incorrect factor of $q$ is still considered like a $p$: 
$$
p\cdot P(a-1) + q \cdot P(a+1) 
= q \left( \frac{q}{p} \right)^a + p \left( \frac{q}{p} \right)^a 
= q \left( \frac{q}{p} \right)^a + (1-q) \left( \frac{q}{p} \right)^a 
$$

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typo to me, if you write:
$$q \cdot P(a-1) = \frac{q^a}{p^{a-1}} = p \cdot \frac{q^a}{p^a}$$
Then the final expression will be:
$$p \cdot P(a+1) + q \cdot P(a-1) = q \cdot \left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^a + p \cdot \left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^a = (p+q) \cdot \left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^a = \left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^a$$
Since, as the author claim, $p+q=1$.